# ggplot2 (and plyr?) fails to plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to use ggplot2 for the first time, code is very simple, but generates errors:

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(2,3,4)

> qplot(a,b)
Error in .Call("split_indices", group, as.integer(n)) : 
  "split_indices" not resolved from current namespace (plyr)

> ggplot(data.frame(a,b), aes(a,b)) +geom_line()
Error in .Call("split_indices", group, as.integer(n)) : 
  "split_indices" not resolved from current namespace (plyr)
```

I verified plyr is installed (v1.8), and ggplot2 (v0.9.3.1). Same error happens with pretty much any example i could find online..

Any ideas here?

**EDIT: Solution may be to re-start RStudio after installing ggplot2 package. I suspect this was done prior to posting question, but unsure.**

Comment: Please post your `sessionInfo()` output from the same session where you can reproduce this error.

Comment: Your error is not reproducible. Both qplot and ggplot work fine with the data you provided. plyr is not even used in your example.

Comment: The error you are seeing is sometimes experienced when attempting to pass large integers. I used your code in R 3.0 with the latest ggplot2 package and did not generate any errors. Is there any code you did not paste that could have assigned a different vector to a or b before attempting to plot it? In other words did you modify your original error prone code to make it cleaner for presentation here? Another reason I think you left something out is that you did not use plyr in anyway as indicated in your question's title.

Comment: FYI -- a coworker had the same problem attempting to run these commands directly after installing ggplot2 on a fresh R 3.0.0 install in RStudio. Restarting RStudio fixed it (as suggested). Thanks.

Comment: I got this also, and restarting RStudio helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have a problem here with the ">".
Try this, which works at my end:

```
require(ggplot2)

a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(2,3,4)

qplot(a,b)
```